# Using string "constructor" as key in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, jasmine, prototype

I'm working on an Exercism JavaScript exercise and I've gotten stuck.  The exercise is to create a function which loops over a string, then creates an object with each word as a key and the number of times that that word appears as the corresponding value.  Simple right?  Well, now I'm stuck on one of the later steps, the input string contains the word "constructor" and you need to put it into the object as a key.  Here's the code I have so far, as well as the Jasmine spec which tests it:

```
function words(words){
    count = {};
    splits = words.split(" ");
    for(var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++){
        splits[i] = splits[i].replace(/[;:!&@$%\^,]/g, "").toLowerCase();
        if([splits[i]] == ""){
            continue;
        }else if(count[splits.i] !== null){
            count[splits[i]]++;
        }else{
            count[splits[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
};

words("constructor Constructor")

describe("words()", function() {
  it("counts constructor", function() {
    var expectedCounts = { constructor: 2 };
    expect(words("constructor Constructor")).toEqual(expectedCounts);
  });
});
```

Problem is, using either dot or bracket notation in the second conditional, it evaluates to true as "constructor" is inherited from the Object prototype up the chain and so it tries to increment a NaN value.  I've tried to find a work around but have come up empty.  And as much as I love JS, it's inheritance has it's quirks.  Is there any way to prevent inheritance in this case or another work around that anyone can think of?

Comment: `constructor` is not your biggest problem. The line `count[splits.i] !== null` is pretty funky. And it wouldn't work like you want it to since this condition will never be `false`. If you change it to `typeof counts[splits[i]] === 'number'`, it should work alright. If you want an object that doesn't inherit anything, you can use `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: One way of avoiding a conflict with existing keys already on the object is to add a `"_"` in front of any key you add both when adding the key or when testing for the existence of the key.  Extra overhead, but essentially gives you your own namespace for your keys.  When iterating keys, use `.hasOwnProperty()` to avoid pre-existing keys.

Comment: count[splits.i] !== null will eval to true if there is no key in the object already so it creates the key to start and sets it's val to 1.  It's worked so far but I like using typeof count[splits.i] === 'number'.  Problem is that this is evaluating to undefined so no progress, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of comparing to `null` to see if you've already set a property on `count`, use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). `hasOwnProperty` doesn't include properties that come from up the prototype chain, only ones directly on the object.

```
if (count.hasOwnProperty(splits[i])) {
    count[splits[i]]++;
} else{
    count[splits[i]] = 1;
}
```